# Getline-like function crashing

Tags: c, crash, malloc, valgrind, free

I'm currently studying programming and I'm on my first year. We're currently studying C and we've been tasked with creating a function that works a bit like *getline()*, but the differences are that the function only takes a file descriptor as parameter and will return on each call a **malloc'd** string that represents the next line in the file corresponding to the file descriptor.

The line that the function returns must not contain any **'\n'** character, must return **NULL** when there is nothing left to read or the functions encounters an error. We're also limited to the following functions: **read, malloc and free.**

I've written the following code (sorry if it's hard to read I'm still learning and we have a "coding style" to follow when writing code):

```
#include "get_next_line.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int find_n(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] == '\n')
            return (i);
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}

static char *my_realloc(char *str, unsigned int size, unsigned int start_at)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *new_str;

    new_str = malloc(size);
    while (str[i + start_at] != '\0') {
        new_str[i] = str[i + start_at];
        i++;
    }
    if (str[i + start_at] == '\0')
        new_str[i] ==  '\0';
    free(str);
    return (new_str);
}

static char *get_line(char *str, unsigned int *total_read)
{
    int i = find_n(str);
    int j = 0;
    int len = 0;
    char *line = malloc(i + 1);

    while (j < i) {
        line[j] = str[j];
        j++;
    }
    line[j] = '\0';
    while (str[i + 1 + len] != '\0') {
        len++;
    }
    *total_read = len;
    str = my_realloc(str, len + 1, i + 1);
    return (line);
}

static void my_strcat(char *dest, char const *src)
{
    int dest_len = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (dest[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }
    dest_len = i;
    i = 0;
    while (src[i] != '\0') {
        dest[dest_len + i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    dest[dest_len + i] = '\0';
}

static char *get_text(int fd, char *str)
{
    char *buf;
    int n_read = READ_SIZE;
    static unsigned int total_read = 0;
    int loop_started = 0;

    buf = malloc(READ_SIZE + 1);
    buf[0] = '\0';
    while (n_read == READ_SIZE) {
        n_read = read(fd, buf, READ_SIZE);
        if (n_read == -1 || (n_read == 0 && !loop_started)) {
            free(str);
            free(buf);
            return (NULL);
        }
        buf[n_read] = '\0';
        total_read += n_read;
        str = my_realloc(str, total_read + 1, 0);
        my_strcat(str, buf);
        loop_started = 1;
        if (find_n(buf)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    free(buf);
    return (get_line(str, &total_read));
}

char *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    static char *str;
    int is_str_malloced = 0;

    if (!is_str_malloced) {
        str = malloc(1);
        str[0] = '\0';
        is_str_malloced = 1;
    }
    return(get_text(fd, str));
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str;
    int fd;

    fd = open("script", O_RDONLY);
    while (1) {
        str = get_next_line(fd);
        if (str == NULL) {
            close(fd);
            return (0);
        }
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    close(fd);
    return (0);
}
```

The main function is pretty much only for testing purposes. When I compile and test this I get:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000000ed71b0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7cbac)[0x7f67d51a5bac]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x87a59)[0x7f67d51b0a59]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x16e)[0x7f67d51b63be]
./a.out[0x40071b]
./a.out[0x40095f]
./a.out[0x400a07]
./a.out[0x400a32]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xea)[0x7f67d514988a]
./a.out[0x40059a]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 103:05 22939320                          /home/ldidierjean/delivery/CPE_getnextline_2017/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 103:05 22939320                          /home/ldidierjean/delivery/CPE_getnextline_2017/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 103:05 22939320                          /home/ldidierjean/delivery/CPE_getnextline_2017/a.out
00ed7000-00ef8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f67d0000000-7f67d0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f67d0021000-7f67d4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f67d4f12000-7f67d4f28000 r-xp 00000000 103:05 7210485                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-7-20170915.so.1
7f67d4f28000-7f67d5127000 ---p 00016000 103:05 7210485                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-7-20170915.so.1
7f67d5127000-7f67d5128000 r--p 00015000 103:05 7210485                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-7-20170915.so.1
7f67d5128000-7f67d5129000 rw-p 00016000 103:05 7210485                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-7-20170915.so.1
7f67d5129000-7f67d52f4000 r-xp 00000000 103:05 7217643                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.25.so
7f67d52f4000-7f67d54f4000 ---p 001cb000 103:05 7217643                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.25.so
7f67d54f4000-7f67d54f8000 r--p 001cb000 103:05 7217643                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.25.so
7f67d54f8000-7f67d54fa000 rw-p 001cf000 103:05 7217643                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.25.so
7f67d54fa000-7f67d54fe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f67d54fe000-7f67d5525000 r-xp 00000000 103:05 7219338                   /usr/lib64/ld-2.25.so
7f67d56f6000-7f67d56f9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f67d5721000-7f67d5724000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f67d5724000-7f67d5725000 r--p 00026000 103:05 7219338                   /usr/lib64/ld-2.25.so
7f67d5725000-7f67d5727000 rw-p 00027000 103:05 7219338                   /usr/lib64/ld-2.25.so
7fff51a9b000-7fff51abd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff51ac2000-7fff51ac5000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff51ac5000-7fff51ac7000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Abandon (core dumped)
```

Valgrind gives me:

```
==6142== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6142== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6142== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6142== Command: ./a.out --track-origins=yes
==6142== 
==6142== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6142==    at 0x400824: my_strcat (get_next_line.c:67)
==6142==    by 0x400960: get_text (get_next_line.c:98)
==6142==    by 0x4009F1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:118)
==6142==    by 0x400A1C: main (get_next_line.c:128)
==6142== 
==6142== Invalid read of size 1
==6142==    at 0x40081F: my_strcat (get_next_line.c:67)
==6142==    by 0x400960: get_text (get_next_line.c:98)
==6142==    by 0x4009F1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:118)
==6142==    by 0x400A1C: main (get_next_line.c:128)
==6142==  Address 0x5214257 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16,759 alloc'd
==6142==    at 0x4C2EB6B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==6142==    by 0x4006B3: my_realloc (get_next_line.c:31)
==6142==    by 0x400949: get_text (get_next_line.c:97)
==6142==    by 0x4009F1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:118)
==6142==    by 0x400A1C: main (get_next_line.c:128)
==6142== 
==6142== Invalid write of size 1
==6142==    at 0x400857: my_strcat (get_next_line.c:73)
==6142==    by 0x400960: get_text (get_next_line.c:98)
==6142==    by 0x4009F1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:118)
==6142==    by 0x400A1C: main (get_next_line.c:128)
==6142==  Address 0x5214270 is 16 bytes after a block of size 16,768 in arena "client"
==6142== 
==6142== Invalid write of size 1
==6142==    at 0x400883: my_strcat (get_next_line.c:76)
==6142==    by 0x400960: get_text (get_next_line.c:98)
==6142==    by 0x4009F1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:118)
==6142==    by 0x400A1C: main (get_next_line.c:128)
==6142==  Address 0x5214277 is 23 bytes after a block of size 16,768 in arena "client"
==6142== 
==6142== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6142==    at 0x4006F7: my_realloc (get_next_line.c:32)
==6142==    by 0x400949: get_text (get_next_line.c:97)
==6142==    by 0x4009F1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:118)
==6142==    by 0x400A1C: main (get_next_line.c:128)
==6142== 
==6142== Invalid read of size 1
==6142==    at 0x4006F2: my_realloc (get_next_line.c:32)
==6142==    by 0x400949: get_text (get_next_line.c:97)
==6142==    by 0x4009F1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:118)
==6142==    by 0x400A1C: main (get_next_line.c:128)
==6142==  Address 0x5214257 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16,759 alloc'd
==6142==    at 0x4C2EB6B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==6142==    by 0x4006B3: my_realloc (get_next_line.c:31)
==6142==    by 0x400949: get_text (get_next_line.c:97)
==6142==    by 0x4009F1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:118)
==6142==    by 0x400A1C: main (get_next_line.c:128)
==6142== 
==6142== Invalid read of size 1
==6142==    at 0x4006D8: my_realloc (get_next_line.c:33)
==6142==    by 0x400949: get_text (get_next_line.c:97)
==6142==    by 0x4009F1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:118)
==6142==    by 0x400A1C: main (get_next_line.c:128)
==6142==  Address 0x5214257 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16,759 alloc'd
==6142==    at 0x4C2EB6B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==6142==    by 0x4006B3: my_realloc (get_next_line.c:31)
==6142==    by 0x400949: get_text (get_next_line.c:97)
==6142==    by 0x4009F1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:118)
==6142==    by 0x400A1C: main (get_next_line.c:128)
==6142== 
==6142== Invalid write of size 1
==6142==    at 0x4006DB: my_realloc (get_next_line.c:33)
==6142==    by 0x400949: get_text (get_next_line.c:97)
==6142==    by 0x4009F1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:118)
==6142==    by 0x400A1C: main (get_next_line.c:128)
==6142==  Address 0x521841e is 0 bytes after a block of size 16,766 alloc'd
==6142==    at 0x4C2EB6B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==6142==    by 0x4006B3: my_realloc (get_next_line.c:31)
==6142==    by 0x400949: get_text (get_next_line.c:97)
==6142==    by 0x4009F1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:118)
==6142==    by 0x400A1C: main (get_next_line.c:128)
==6142== 
==6142== Invalid read of size 1
==6142==    at 0x40070A: my_realloc (get_next_line.c:36)
==6142==    by 0x400949: get_text (get_next_line.c:97)
==6142==    by 0x4009F1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:118)
==6142==    by 0x400A1C: main (get_next_line.c:128)
==6142==  Address 0x5214277 is 23 bytes after a block of size 16,768 in arena "client"
==6142== 
--6142-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
--6142-- si_code=1;  Faulting address: 0x206991B288;  sp: 0x1002ba9e30

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal

host stacktrace:
==6142==    at 0x5804F2DC: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==6142==    by 0x5800B304: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==6142==    by 0x5800B4D2: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==6142==    by 0x58098653: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==6142==    by 0x580A7256: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 6142)
==6142==    at 0x4C2EB6B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==6142==    by 0x4006B3: my_realloc (get_next_line.c:31)
==6142==    by 0x400949: get_text (get_next_line.c:97)
==6142==    by 0x4009F1: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:118)
==6142==    by 0x400A1C: main (get_next_line.c:128)


Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution.
It contains workarounds to several common problems.
In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after
identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance
that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or
crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.

If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org

In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind
version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.
```

It looks like the free() in the my_realloc function is causing the program to crash, but I can't find out why at all, can somebody help me?

Comment: how are we to test this without the contents of the header file: `get_next_line.h`?

Comment: usually, when a call to `free()` crashes, it means the heap has been corrupted.  This is often due to overflowing a buffer that is allocated in the heap.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation function: ( malloc, calloc, realloc ), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `open()` always check the returned value.  a value of -1 means an error occurred.  When an error occurs, call `perror()` to output the enclosed text and the reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `int is_str_malloced = 0; if (!is_str_malloced)`  the `is_str_malloced` will ALWAYS be 0, so the `if` code block will always be entered.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>` to expose the function: `read()`

Comment: there is the concept of the `file position pointer (FPP)`.   After the posted code 'reads' a line from the input file, the FPP will be far beyond the beginning of the next line in the input file.  This means the next call to `get_next_line()` will (effectively) skip portions of the input file.  (and what happens when the calling program is wanting to read from more than 1 input file?)

Comment: in `main()`   the variable `str`  will contain a pointer to allocated memory.  The pointer to the allocated memory needs to be passed to `free()` before exiting the program.  Note: `free()` has no problem with being passed a NULL pointer.  Suggest also initializing `str` to NULL.

Comment: Since the posted code is trying to replace the system `getline()`, suggest looking at the source code for `getline()`, [source](https://dev.w3.org/libwww/Library/src/vms/getline.c)  and to implement all the functionality of `getline()`, including returning the length of the read in line.  Note: unlike the referenced version of `getline()` I would not limit the length to 256 bytes

Comment: in function: `main()`, this: `while (1)
    {
        str = get_next_line(fd);
        if (str == NULL)
        {
            close(fd);
            return (0);
        }`  should probably be replaced with: `while( (str = get_next_line( fd ) ) != NULL ) {`

Comment: the code in `get_next_line()` could be replaced with: `static char *str;  return get_text( fd, str );`

Comment: get_next_line.h only contains a declaration of my get_next_line() function to be used in other projects

Comment: And the macro READ_SIZE that is used to change the number of bytes read each time read() is called

Comment: I'll try to correct my code using the information you've given me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rebuilding your `realloc` can be a good idea!**

Think about the `start_at` value you give to your `realloc`.

An easier way to realloc:

```
char            *my_realloc(char *old, int size)
{
  int           i = 0;
  char          *new;

  new = malloc(sizeof(char) * (my_strlen(old) + size));
  while (old[i] != '\0')
    {
      new[i] = old[i];
      i++;
    }
  free(old);
  return (new);
}
```

Also, I prefer to `malloc` like this:

```
malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
```

And it's better for this projet to have a `get_char`:

```
char get_char(const int fd)
{
  static char buff[READ_MAX];
  static char* pointer;
  static int len = 0;
  char caracter;

  if (len == 0)
    {
      len = read(fd, buff, READ_MAX);
      pointer = (char*)&buff;
      if (len == 0)
        return (0);
    }
  caracter = *pointer;
  pointer++;
  len--;
  return caracter;
}
```

Good luck!